# Angular HTTP: Status -1 and CORS

Tags: angularjs, http, cors, http-status-codes, angular-http

In our angular application sometimes we get http status -1 returned to us. The status -1 happens on a popup that is closed, so the user isn't affected by it, just our logs.

I attempted to handle it by doing

```
      switch (response.status) {
        case 0:
          break;
        case -1:
          break;
        case 401:
          localStorageService.clearAll();
          redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url = $location.path();
          $location.path('/login');
```

Which was suggested in [AngularJS Issue #12920](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12920)

We are definitely getting less logs in, but there are still some HTTP -1 status codes. Is there a different way I should be handling the -1?

Answer (score 2):

When the request is aborted or timed-out, the request lands as an error with status -1.

Taken from [the official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> Also, status codes less than -1 are normalized to zero. -1 usually means the request was aborted, e.g. using a `config.timeout`.
>
> `timeout – {number|Promise}` – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that
>   should abort the request when resolved.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the most common cause of status of a `-1`, is that the browser blocked the response because of a violation of [Same Origin Policy.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. For example, [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) follow the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). So, a web application using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) *could only* make HTTP requests to its own domain. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors to allow cross-domain requests.

[image]

The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) mechanism gives web servers cross-domain access controls, which enable secure cross-domain data transfers. Modern browsers use CORS in an API container - such as [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) - to mitigate risks of cross-origin HTTP requests.

See [Use CORS to allow cross-origin access.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)