# angularjs $http always return -1 with response status 404

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I found a strange question in angular $http.

My request code

```
  $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/server/'
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.status);
    },function(response){
      console.log(response.status);
    });
```

Before that, I set the request header

```
app.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', function($q) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic *';
                return config;
            },
            requestError: function(rejectReason) {
                return $q.reject(rejectReason);
            },
            response: function(response) {
                return $q.resolve(response);
            },
            responseError: function(response) {
                console.log(response.status);
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
    }]);
```

This page does not exist,so it should return 404,but it returns -1.

If remove this line`config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic *';`,it returns right 404.

Can anybody help me，this is my demo page http://plnkr.co/edit/GhghMNCPcITwXCINISW5?p=preview , thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTTP: Status -1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418688/angular-http-status-1)

Comment: Are you sure your server returns a 404? Check the network panel for the status code returned by the server. Most probably the connection timed out, and the server didn't respond with a status code.

Comment: What is the URL in the address bar of your browser?

Comment: @NikhilBhandari Yes i'm sure,my chrome returns 404,but `console.log` returns -1 in angular code.

Comment: @JBNizet 
You can look this http://plnkr.co/edit/GhghMNCPcITwXCINISW5?p=preview, it can reproduce my problem.Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. This is a simple question, and it matters, because it's probably a CORS problem. Why don't you just answer it? There is no way I can know the answer by looking at your plunkr. Your server probably has CORS enabled, but doesn't authorize the Authorization header.

Comment: @JBNizet Is right. It is most likely a [CORS problem.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: @JBNizet Thank your.It is really blocked when OPTIONS,
but what should I do?

Comment: I think it's time to close this question.In my case the server set `response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')` in response heasers.Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

There are something wrong with your URL over which you are making request.

One can tell by updating the http call backs as follow :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'angular'
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://cloudzone.eicp.net:8155/server/'
  }).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
  }).error(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
  });
});
```

You will see that the server is neither returning Success nor Error, it is just getting timeout.
Please check the server's availability.

Suggestion: Try some utility such as 'postman' in google chrome and see what results you are getting.

Comment: The `.success` method does not return status as a property of a response object. The **deprecated** way: `$http(...).success(function onSuccess(data, status, headers, config)`. See [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/5535245)

Comment: @Harsh Thank you for your answer.I keep testing.

Comment: @georgeawg that is fine, i was suggesting to test the sever's availability; if the URL is actually responding to the requests.